# Intel® Wireless 7265 device hangs when under load

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, kde, intel, iwlwifi

i own a Dell XPS 13 9343 with a Intel 7265 Card. 
When i stress too much the card downloading some stuff the card stops working and i need to turn off/turn on the software switch manually.

I'm running Linux Mint 18.1 KDE Edtion, i didn't change the standard kernel and i've added drivers listed [here](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#and_7265_support) for my card.

I can easily cause the problem by downloading some large files at once so could be easy to troubleshoot.

The problem does not appear in Windows (i have a dual boot configuration).

Comment: Dell XPS 13 is known to have interferences between the USB interface and Wifi. Are you using the USB interface?

Comment: You can [edit here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/365560/edit) without removing the old post

Comment: There are BIOS patches for the Dell XPS. What they do is steal potency to the wifi card...the Windows drivers are probably already doing that (I guess).

Comment: My XPS is already patched with latest BIOS patch (A11)